# one factor model for forward curve - Clewlow and Strickland

Tags: forward-curve, ode

In their book, Energy Derivatives Pricing and Risk Mgmt, the authors introduce a one factor SDE for the forward curve as follows:

$\frac{dF}{F} = \sigma e^{-c(T-t)} dW$

F(t) is the forward curve at time t,
sigma is vol, c is a constant and dW is the increment to the Weiner process.

The intent is to create a forward curve that decays over time and the constant c determines the degree of the decay.
I wanted to solve the SDE, but for starters, I thought I'd start without the stochastic (dZ) term

I have attached my solution (for the nonstochastic diff equation) in the screenshot clewlo_soln, but something seems off here.....as the curve generated by the equation (e.g. numerical excel implementation) shows exponential growth instead of a decay!! So I must be doing something wrong in the solution......would appreciate some advice.

[[image: attempted solution to non-stochastic forward curve eq.1]

Comment: FWIW a writeup by Clewlow and Strickland on their 1 factor model is here https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=160608 . Though it may not address your specific question.